# Jackson mapping: Deserialization of JSON with different property names

Tags: java, json, json-deserialization

I have a server that returns a json string:

```
{"pId": "ChIJ2Vn0h5wOlR4RsOSteUYYM6g"}
```

Now, I can use jackson to deserialize it into an object with the variable called pId, but I don't want the variable to be called pId, I would rather deserialize it to placeId.

Current object in android java:

```
public class Place {

    private String pId;

}
```

What I want the object to look like:

```
public class Place {

    private String placeId;

}
```

If I change the object's variable to placeId, jackson will not be able to deserialize the JSON as the property names no longer matches.

Is there a jackson annotation I can used to map the "placeId" variable in the java object to the JSON string variable "pId" returned back from the server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `@JsonProperty` annotation:

```
public class Place {

    @JsonProperty("pId")
    private String placeId;

}
```

For more information you can see the related [javadoc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html).